# Hardware virtualization is not supported on MacBookPro 2010

Tags: virtualization

I have a MacBook Pro 2010 where I've installed Windows8 using Bootcamp. When I install Visual Studio 2012 with WindowsPhone8 SDK, it says me that my hardware does not support hardware virtualization, so that the emulator cannot be used.

Is that true? Do you know if there is a way to enable the virtualization?

Comment: It would be useful to know exactly which model you have, particularly which CPU.

Comment: Do you have a 13-inch model? The 13-inch 2010 had a Core 2 processor, which does not support virtualization. The 15 and 17-inch models had i5 or i7 processors, which do.

Comment: yes, i have a Core2 processor..:-[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows phone 8 requires SLAT to run with the emulator provided by hyper-v, so yes, we with "old" hardware are out. :(